# Is there a analternative to powertoys quick accent I can use on fedora linux?

Tags: linux

I just switched to linux and I mostly don't miss anything the only thing I got verry ussed to is powertoys quick accent. Is there an alternative I can use on fedora linux?

Comment: I don't think there is. Maybe you can use something like this https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/bwofdu/comment/eq017u6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3